# Inserting iframe right after <body> on header.php

Tags: headers

I have an iframe tracking script of sorts that I need to add right after the body tag. After looking around on the web, I found that the body tag is in header.php and I should add a function to functions.php and then add the html to header.php. Not sure if this is right but...

I went to *functions.php* and added this:

```
function after_body(){
    do_action('after_body');
}
```

Then I went back to *header.php*, looked up to where the body tag was and added this:

```
<body><?php after_body(); ?>
```

But where exactly do I add my html/iframe code?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly write iframe after body tag in header.php
IF you want add function overthere then write this code in function.php file.

```
function after_body(){
  echo '<iframe src=""></iframe>'; 
}
```